# jQueryUI widget text plus icon

Tags: jquery-ui

I have:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
   <div class="ui-widget-header">
      My Menu<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span>
   </div>
   <ul class="ui-widget-content">
      <li>Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Menu Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Right now, the ui-icon is appearing below "My Menu"

Q: How can I get "My Menu" to appear on the same line as the UI widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the style "display: inline-block;" to ui-icon,
or wrap My Menu in a span and use floats

Comment: Thanks David!  "The element will generate a block box, laid out as an inline box".  What does that mean?

Comment: that means you can set the width, height, and margin (box properties) of the ui-icon span (which you normally can't with a span). Being inline, it won't push everything around it to the next line like a div (which is block, or non-inline)